# Match start of line return text after match

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make a REGEX to extract the text after `First name:`, `Last name:`, `Email:` and not included the label.

Here is my text between the tags.

```
<MyText>
First name: Chris
Last name: Jones
Email: cj@dsf.com
</myText>
```

I've been playing around with something like this: `/(Last name:).*?` But that doesn't work. Do anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Which dialect of regular expressions are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Wouter!

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Can't you just take everything after the `: `?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes has to be regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a .NET Regex, you can use positive lookbehind assertions:

```
new Regex(@"(?<=Last name:).*");
```

Depending on context you may have to be careful, though - the JavaScript regular expression engine doesn't support lookbehind assertions, so you couldn't, for example, use this client-side in an ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator.

Comment: ah this is the one! "(?<=Last name:).*" I did not need the ? at the end#

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know your scripting language (the REGEX support can be difference). But something like this should work:

```
/^.*?:(.*?)$/m
```

Some explaination:

A regex with `m` modifier (`//m`) means that `^` and `$` match the begin and end of each line, not the begin and end of a string.

The `.*?:` part matches `Last name:`, `First name:`, ect. and because it is not between parentheses (`()`), this is not captured.

The `(.*?)` part matches everything that is after the colon (`:`) and because the `$` is placed after it, it will match everything until the end of the line. It is between parentheses, meaning that it will be captured.

---

To answer your edit, use this:

```
/^First name: (.*?)$/m
/^Last name: (.*?)$/m
/^Email: (.*?)$/m
```

Comment: This does not work. I want three regex in total one for each label

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:

```
/^.*?: (.*)$/
```

Comment: Sorry Champ, I want three regex in total one for each label, first last and email. returning the text after the :